# Nokia HERE Maps: Letting user draw rectangle on map

Tags: drawing, rectangles, here-api

using Nokia HERE maps api:

There is a useful post about how to let user draw a polygon, but I need to restrict that to rectangle.

Can anyone suggest a way of letting user draw a rectangle please?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extension of creating a [draggable marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058931/here-javascript-api-3-0-how-to-implement-a-draggable-marker). You will need to add two markers to the map (say `startHandle` and `endHandle` and place them in an `H.map.group` called `rectHandles`). Add a '`drag`' handler to the group so that whenever one of them is moved, the associated rectangle to display is calculated and updated.

```
rectHandles.addEventListener('drag', function () {

  var rect = H.geo.Rect.coverPoints([startHandle.getPosition(),
   endHandle.getPosition()]);
  rectangle.setBounds(rect);

});
```

Where `rectangle` is just an instance of  `H.map.Rect`